# Chartjs stacked bar single max value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible to use chartjs stacked bar with one max value?

I have two values. One is sales and second is net revenue which is made from sales.

I want to show both, but I don't want to have revenue added on top of the sales value since it's already part of it.

data

```
sales (max value) | earning   
500               | 100
300               | 30
```

now it is showing 600 and 330, rather than keeping it to 500 and 300.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Sales',
        data: [500, 300],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 2
      },
      {
        label: 'Earning',
        data: [100, 30],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to subtract the second value from the first one before the chart initializes, so that, it doesn't draw the graph with combined values.

To accomplish so, you can use the following chart plugin ...

```
plugins: [{
   beforeInit: function(c) {
      var data1 = c.data.datasets[0].data;
      var data2 = c.data.datasets[1].data;
      c.data.datasets[0].data = data1.map(function(e, i) {
         return e - data2[i];
      });
   }
}]
```

add this plugin followed by your chart options.

**UPDATE**

use the following tooltips callback function to show the old values on tooltip's label ...

```
tooltips: {
   callbacks: {
      label: function(t, d) {
         var dst1_label = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + (+t.yLabel + d.datasets[1].data[t.index]);
         var dst2_label = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + t.yLabel;
         if (t.datasetIndex === 0) return dst1_label;
         else return dst2_label;
      }
   }
}
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Sales',
         data: [500, 300],
         backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
         ],
         borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
         ],
         borderWidth: 2
      }, {
         label: 'Earning',
         data: [100, 30],
         backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
         ],
         borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
         ],
         borderWidth: 2
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }],
         xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      },
      tooltips: {
         callbacks: {
            label: function(t, d) {
               var dst1_label = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + (+t.yLabel + d.datasets[1].data[t.index]);
               var dst2_label = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + t.yLabel;
               if (t.datasetIndex === 0) return dst1_label;
               else return dst2_label;

            }
         }
      }
   },
   plugins: [{
      beforeInit: function(c) {
         var data1 = c.data.datasets[0].data;
         var data2 = c.data.datasets[1].data;
         c.data.datasets[0].data = data1.map(function(e, i) {
            return e - data2[i];
         });
      }
   }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: It is perfect, but get messed up at the labels, because labels still need to show 500 and not 400 for sales.

Comment: You mean the y-axis labels?

Comment: but, if you change it from 400 to 500 for sales then that won't make sense. both sales and earning can't be at 500, it'll exclude earning from the graph. or is that you want?

Comment: sales is still 500 and 100 is our earning from that sales.

Comment: okay, maybe I'm not getting you correctly. can you share an image of your expected chart?

Comment: what you did was perfect in chart bar wise. that is exactly what I wanted, but the labels need to still show old values and not the new values we set from javascript. I hope that clears it.

Comment: wait.. are you talking about the y-axis labels *(the one on the left hand side)* or the tooltip's label *(that pops up when you hover on the bar)* ?

Comment: you need to use a callback function for tooltip's label to show the old values. check updated answer

Comment: I have tried this before, then the numbers get into 499.9934333 values if there are pennies

Comment: then just `round` it or use `toFixed(2)`